# Installing 64-bit Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

Have Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit (No SP-1 yet). When installed, have both IE 8 32-bit & IE-64bit.  I want to upgrade to IE9; when I loaded IE9 32-bit and selected up grade it asked me to save IE-64bit. I have also found IE9 32-bit but this time do I install both or not, can't find infomation about this subject?

Answer (score 1):

Download the x64 bit version. It is the correct setup for your machine and should upgrade you to IE9. It will install both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions on your computer.